Handling Long Content Updates Without Page Jumps or Blank Screens
I'm developing a chat interface in SwiftUI. The goal is to dynamically update the chat view with the server's responses, ensuring that the newest messages always appear at the bottom of the visible area.
For short responses, the implementation works fine. However, issues arise with longer messages: the chat view either jumps or goes blank temporarily as the conversation progresses. It seems like the view struggles to handle the refresh when dealing with lengthy content, leading to a less smooth user experience. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have suggestions on how to maintain a fluid chat interface with streaming updates, especially with long messages?
I found it works well when use ScrollView + VStack, issue will happen in ScrollView + LazyVStack.
Code is as bellow:
import SwiftUI

struct ChatMessage: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String = ""
    var isSender: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var messages: [ChatMessage] = []
    @State var refreshFlag = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 16) {
                        ForEach(messages) { message in
                            HStack {
                                if message.isSender {
//                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(message.text)
                                        .padding()
                                        .background(Color.blue)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                } else {
                                    Text(message.text)
                                        .padding()
                                        .background(Color.gray)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                    //Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(height: 1)
                            .id("Bottom")
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .onChange(of: refreshFlag) { _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        proxy.scrollTo("Bottom")
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack() {
                Button("Clear") {
                    messages = []
                    refreshFlag.toggle()
                    //sendMessage()
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                Button("Send") {
                    sendMessage()
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            
        }
    }


    func simulateTypingEffect() async {
        let len: Int = messages.count <= 2 ? 450 : Int.random(in: 8...20)
        let newMessage: String = randomWordsString(wordCount: len)
        
        var msg: ChatMessage = ChatMessage(text: "", isSender: false)
        msg.text = newMessage
        messages.append(msg)
        refreshFlag.toggle()
    }
  
    func sendMessage() {
        let len: Int = Int.random(in: 8...20)
        let newMessage = ChatMessage(text: randomWordsString(wordCount: len), isSender: true)
        messages.append(newMessage)
        refreshFlag.toggle()
        Task {
            await simulateTypingEffect()
        }
    }
    
    func randomWordsString(wordCount: Int) -> String {
        let words = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "date", "elderberry", "fig", "grape", "honeydew", "kiwi", "lemon", "mango", "nectarine", "orange", "papaya", "quince", "raspberry", "strawberry", "tangerine", "ugli", "vanilla", "watermelon", "xigua", "yam", "zucchini"]
        var sentence: [String] = []
        
        for _ in 0..<wordCount {
            if let randomWord = words.randomElement() {
                sentence.append(randomWord)
            }
        }
        
        return sentence.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

Screen recording:


@Asperi Need your help~
